# How to avoid inner query im MYSQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table with 4.7 million rows and I am executing this query on this table:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE `eid` IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT `eid` FROM students WHERE code IN ('120', '330'));
```

This is working fine but it slows down the performance. How can I boost up performance by changing this query or how can I do the same work with some other optimized query (in better way)?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? It would be good to add the `SHOW CREATE students;` output and the EXPLAIN output in the question as well.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is not needed and I doubt MySQL will optimize that way

Comment: `IN` can be really slow for large sets. Try using a proper join.

Answer (score 0):

Having no idea of your table... The first thing to try would be to

```
CREATE INDEX i_code ON students (code);
CREATE INDEX i_eid ON students (eid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an [`EXISTS` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).. Generally faster and safer.

```
SELECT *
FROM students AS s1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT `eid`
  FROM students AS s2
  WHERE code IN ('120', '330')
  AND s1.eid = s2.eid
);
```

Or, if it's really that simple, and you're just making assumptions about the planner in an attempt to make it faster, benchmark it against this. I'm not sure exactly why you're asking about this, but `IN` is usually not what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM students AS s1
WHERE code IN ('120', '330');
```